# Backbone Collections Models Not Accessible

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm having trouble with models disappearing after populating a Backbone collection from a url. The code works if I just pass the array into the collection.

The collection:

```
var CustomerList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
     model: Customer,
     url: "/customer_list/json"
});
```

the url returns:

```
[
   {
      "id":"870000",
      "name":"vitae odio",
      "contact_name1":"ame",
      "contact_number1":"345634565246",
      "contact_name2":"",
      "contact_number2":"",
      "address_line1":"Ap #489-8375 Ornare, Ave2",
      "address_line2":"",
      "town":"Stillwater",
      "county":"Herefordshire",
      "postcode":"JV5H 2QH",
      "email":"parturient@vitae.edu",
      "created_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00",
      "updated_at":"2012-08-18 16:44:36"
   },
   {
      "id":"870001",
      "name":"mauris, aliquam",
      "contact_name1":"Quail",
      "contact_number1":"82733186940",
      "contact_name2":null,
      "contact_number2":null,
      "address_line1":"Ap #921-368 Cras Ave",
      "address_line2":null,
      "town":"Lake Charles",
      "county":"Essex",
      "postcode":"AP6 0KZ",
      "email":"vitae.dolor@Quisque.edu",
      "created_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00",
      "updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"
   }
]
```

The view:

```
$(function() {

/* Customer View */
var CustomerView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'tr',
    className: 'customer-row',
    template: _.template($('#customerRowTemplate').html()),

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this.el;
    }
});

/* Customer List View */
var CustomerListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#customers'),

    initialize: function() {
        this.collection = new CustomerList();
        this.collection.bind('reset', this.render());
        this.collection.fetch();
    },

    render: function() {
        console.log(this.collection);
        console.log(this.collection.models);

        _.each(this.collection.models, function(customer) {
            this.renderCustomer(customer);
        }, this);
    },

    renderCustomer: function(customer) {
        var customerView = new CustomerView({
            model: customer
        });

        var html = customerView.render();

        this.$el.find('#customer-list').append(html);
    }
});

var customerList = new CustomerListView();

});
```

When calling console.log(this.collection); it shows the model array has a length of 366 and I can view all of the models in the inspector.

But when calling console.log(this.collection.models); it returns an empty array. Which means that the collection is not iterated over and therefore never rendered. Again this works fine if I just pass in the customer list manually.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't put your whole application definition inside a `$()` ready callback... just leave your view instantiation in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here: `this.collection.bind('reset', this.render());`

`this.render()` should be `this.render`. Using parentheses calls the function on the spot, before the collection has a chance to fetch the models.

You should also pass the context to the `render` function. This can be done in 2 ways:

- Add `_.bindAll(this, "render")` to the CustomerListView `initialize` method.
- `this.collection.bind('reset', this.render, this)` - add `this` as the third argument.

**EDIT**

For version 0.9.9 and above, use `this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render)`

Comment: Thank you, that solved it! I used this.collection.bind('reset', this.render, this); although I still don't really understand what passing this as the context actually does!

Comment: My pleasure. The 3rd argument makes sure that the "this" in render is the same as the "this" in initialize (the one the has the collection attached to it).

Comment: Nowadays, you should do `this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render)`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to bind anything with Backbone. It is using undescore correctly under the hood. You are not correctly using the each method neither.

Furthermore, if you want to bind an action, you must use the function name, and not executing it :

```
this.collection.bind('reset', this.render);
```

instead of

```
 this.collection.bind('reset', this.render());
```

I would try also :

```
initialize: function() {
    this.collection = new CustomerList();
    this.collection.fetch();
},

render: function() {
    console.log(this.collection);
    console.log(this.collection.models);

    this.collection.each(function(customer) {
        this.renderCustomer(customer);
    });
}
```

What do you want exactly with 'reset' ? the bind function is NOT in the [Backbone API](http://backbonejs.org/). Did you meant 'on' ?

Comment: Thank you for the response. The idea with this.collection.bind('reset', this.render); was to call the render function when the collection had finished fetching. Is this not the correct way to approach this? edit: just looking into the Backbone API and bind is an alias of on.

Comment: Using `_.each(collection.models, ...)` is okay but using the [mixed-in Underscore methods](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods), `collection.each(...)`, is definitely better form and probably a better idea.

Comment: @jmahony ok, I was just not sure of the `bind` thing. So you should think about empty your divs at rendring time, or tour data will be filled many times ;)